# How to run docker container from non-root user?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How do I make a docker container run as non-root user and have working directory (and its files) owned by a non-root user. Variants I could find in various online tutorials didn't work for some reason, files in `/var/www` would still be owned by `root root`.

Below is my `Dockerfile`, I use `docker-compose` to build and run containers. Host system is Windows 10.

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

ARG user
ARG uid

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this docker file

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

ARG user
ARG uid

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

RUN addgroup -g $uid $user && \
    adduser -S -G $user -u $uid -h $user

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN chown $user:$user -R /var/www

WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

This change is needed to make sure that the user is created in the docker image

```
RUN addgroup -g $uid $user && \
    adduser -S -G $user -u $uid -h $user
```

This is needed to change the ownership of the files to the new user

```
RUN chown $user:$user -R /var/www
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add

```
RUN chown $user:$user -R /var/www
```

before your WORKDIR instruction. Similarly you can change ownership for other locations as needed.